# Express API - Verifying req.body elements

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Am building an api using express and node.js.

I'm working on basic validation and want to verify items being passed in exist and are safe (done in addition to validation on client side).

So i have teh following:

```
router.post('/register', function(req, res) {

  for (var itemsFromBody in req.body){
    console.log(itemsFromBody);

}
```

However when i check the console all i see are the names of the Keys e.g. username, email etc, not the values themselves.

How do i obtain those?

Also I'll be doing validation on those eg making sure its not empty - do i need to follow a simple if-then statement or is there some nice npm package that exists that allows me to verify?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (var itemsFromBodyIndex in req.body){
    if (req.body.hasOwnProperty(itemsFromBodyIndex)) {
       console.log(req.body[itemsFromBodyIndex]);
    }
}
```

This should work !

Useful links:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Instructions/for...in
- https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Object/hasOwnProperty

And what about an error catcher into the loop if all of your fields are required ?

```
for (var itemsFromBodyIndex in req.body){
    if (req.body.hasOwnProperty(itemsFromBodyIndex)) {
        console.log(req.body[itemsFromBodyIndex]);

        if(req.body[itemsFromBodyIndex] == null){
            // handle empty field            
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thats great - all works.
And do you know of any nice package that can allow me to do such validations or is my own code best?

Comment: I think your own code could be easier for simple testing, but for more complex test, there's a lot of module available. You could try one of them :)
https://www.google.fr/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=node%20js%20field%20validation%20module&oq=node%20js%20field%20validation%20module&aqs=chrome..69i57.8119j0j7

Comment: Thanks. I tried express-validator and it works well. However i ended writing and using my own code as its a simple application i need for.

Answer (score 0):

The `for -- in` will only give you keys, as you noticed above. You need to use those keys to get the values

```
for (var itemsFromBody in req.body){
    console.log("Key: " + itemsFromBody + " Value: " + req.body[itemsFromBody]);
}
```